# Is there a way to use hashmap/list as jq tool condition building block?

Tags: jq

I have set of jsons in a file as input

I am looking for a way to keep only those objects that meet the following (pseudo-jq) condition:

single_json[key] IN List

where List is predefined list of values (around 50k) - stored in another file (lets say one value per line)

Is smth like that possible and **feasible**? thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can read in your list of predefined values using one of the command-line options, e.g.

   jq --argfile list FILEPATH ...

This makes the contents of the file available as $list

2. To check whether a JSON value is in an array, you could use `index/1`, e.g. using this helper function:

   def check: . as $in | $list | index($in);

(It probably isn't necessary to use such a helper function, but it illustrates the idea.)

3. Without more specifics, it's difficult to be more specific, so for now let me just wish you good luck!